# JSON Parser Error Unexpected Token Error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I recently cloned my Rails app, which was developed on Linux, to my Windows OS. There were a few errors, and I managed to fix most of them except this one. This error pops up when I try to access my page locally:

> JSON::ParserError
>   419: unexpected token at ''

This is the code in question:

```
<head>
  <title>DemoApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

I researched and couldn't find a straightforward solution to this. I had previously changed my **runtimes.rb** to 'UTF-8' so that it will run in Windows.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of a [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom) or a tabulation space, it happens to me when I try to paste inside Vim.